# My Custom MysqliDatabase class doesn't return an instance of mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

For reference, I have 3 classes + interface:

- `DBFactory`
- `AbstractDB`
- `DBIntreface`
- `MysqliDatabase`

As far as I can tell, the problem is solely with `MysqliDatabase`

```
class MysqliDatabase extends AbstractDB {

    public function __construct()
    {
        return new mysqli(
            $GLOBALS['host'],
            $GLOBALS['user'],
            $GLOBALS['pass'],
            $GLOBALS['database']
        );
    }
}
```

Right now, all I want to do is have a class that creates the mysqli connection. If I copy the code to my main script and run it, it works. However, in the class it does not.

Can someone tell me why?

**Edit**

I've also tried this, and a few variations:

`MysqliDatabase`

```
class MysqliDatabase extends AbstractDB {

    public $db;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $db = new mysqli(
            $GLOBALS['host'],
            $GLOBALS['user'],
            $GLOBALS['pass'],
            $GLOBALS['database']
        );
        $this->db = $db;

        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before anyone says anything, I will probably replace `$GLOBALS` with constants or something else.

Comment: You can't return anything from a class constructor. You should set a property instead.

Comment: @jeroen You mean like my edit?

Comment: You still can't return anything from a class constructor. You need to remove the last line of your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `MysqliDatabase` **does not extent** the `mysql` class. One solution would be to extend the `mysql` class directly and add any `AbstractDB` methods via interfaces. Another is to use the `factory pattern`

The **class constructor can only return an instance of the class** (except when using javascript which is not object-oriented in the strict sense)

Comment: You mean the class the constructor is in, and not just an instance of any class?

Comment: @nobrandheroes, yes exactly, each constructor is for a specific class and only that, so nothing else can be returned form the constructor, try the factory pattern if you want to deal with multiple DB's transparently

Comment: I already have a factor pattern in place, but thanks to you I've figured out a solution. Thanks.